# How to run python script using keyboard lib as root and also have access to the packages on the project venv?

Tags: python

I have a python project which uses a specific venv. I tried to use the "keyboard" package on it, but I got the error "ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.". Then I installed the package with `sudo python3.9 -m pip install keyboard` and tried to run the script like `sudo python3.9 path/to/script`. It seems that the root problem was solved, but now I get `ModuleNotFoundError:` for every package I used on the script that was installed on the project's venv.